# slider in jquery ui doesnt work properly when using route in angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jquery-ui, angular-ui-router

It basically works (slider shows up) when I run this file directly. But when i run index.html and call it by angular ui route, the slider doesnt show up anymore. it also works when using href tag to link to this file. Please help, i have been fixing this all day. 
Ps. if i have to show more codes ( eg., controller or service ), you can tell me.
Thanks

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.ui.theme.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.ui.slider.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" type="text/css" />

<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.ui.mouse.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.ui.slider.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('#slider1').slider({
        value:12,
        min: 10,
        max: 20,
        step: 1,
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
            $('#font_size').val(ui.value + ' px');
            $('.box').css('font-size', ui.value);
        }
    });
    }); 

</script>

<div class="examples">
    <h2>Text animation with jQuery and UI slider</h2>
    <div class="column">
        <p>
            <label for="font_size">Font size:</label>
            <input type="text" id="font_size" style="border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;" />
        </p>
        <div id="slider1"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="box">A man bribes a rabbit with wicked dentures to run away with him in a sailboat via an ambulance. Bribing Koalas to remain illegally in one place. Trees anchor me in place. / Your mom drives the ambulance, but the city is farther than it appears.</div>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
```